# Run for loop without overwriting existing elements in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R, and I am currently struggling with a for loop.

My code is going to simulate 8 stock prices from time 0, where the stock price is 100, until time 8. I want to do this 10 times, and store all the values in a vector, price. My vector will in the end consist of 80 prices. However, the only values that are stored in the vector is the last simulation. I don't know how to store all of the values without overwriting the existing elements. Does anyone have a clue on how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
S = c(100)
delta = 0.25
sigma = 0.2
rf = 0.01

prices = c()

Ber.reg <- function(S, delta, sigma, rf) {
    for(i in 1:10) {
      for(j in 1:8) {
        S[j+1] <- S[j]*exp((rf - 0.5*sigma^2)*delta + sigma*sqrt(delta)*rnorm(1))
      }
    prices <- S
    }
return(prices)
}
```

Comment: `prices <- c(prices, S)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1) A function which depends on global variables being properly initialized prior to running is a fragile function. It is poor design to have `prices` global. It should be local to the function.

2) They only relevant thing about `S` is the value `100`. That initial price should be the parameter, wrapping it in `c()` is needlessly obscure (though harmless since 100 *is* `c(100)`). Conceptually, 100 is a scalar

3) Your code is 10 runs of a simulation, where each simulation has 8 transition steps. Why not a) make these numbers parameters rather than hard-wiring them in? and b) return a *matrix* where each row is a run? Logically, you have more of a matrix than a flat vector.

4) Growing vectors (e.g. `price <- c(price,S)`) is inefficient since it is repeatedly allocating more space and copying the old values into new space. Since you know the size of the output ahead of time, allocate the space once and for all.

5) Make your code more vectorized. Start with a vector of the initial values repeated for the number of trials, and at each stage, update that entire vector in a single line of code, with no inner loop required:

```
Ber.reg <- function(initial, delta, sigma, rf,runs,steps){
  n <- runs*(steps+1)
  prices <- vector("numeric",n)
  price <- rep(initial,runs)
  prices[1:runs] <- price
  for(i in seq_len(steps)){
    price <- price*exp((rf - 0.5*sigma^2)*delta + sigma*sqrt(delta)*rnorm(runs))
    prices[(1+ i*runs):((i+1)*runs)] <- price
  }
  dim(prices) <- c(runs,steps+1)
  prices
}
```

For example, using your values for `delta, sigma, rf`:

```
> Ber.reg(100,delta,sigma,rf,3,4)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  100  94.72913  94.35394  92.47475  90.03819
[2,]  100  91.91992  85.05428  83.87200  65.26291
[3,]  100 120.12281 121.45070 131.76266 124.25140
```

Your code would be (almost) equivalent to

```
prices <- Ber.reg(100,delta,sigma,rf,10,8)
```

If you really wanted a flat vector the do this to the output:

```
prices <- as.vector(t(prices))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your approach was definitely more effective when simulating 100,000 paths, which is what I'm supposed to do

Comment: @KristianLomheim  A recently published book that has so-far been an eye-opening experience for me (I'm about half done with it now) is "Efficient R Programming" by Gillespie and Lovelace. One of their tips (which can also be found in other sources) is to "never grow an object" but to instead pre-allocate whenever possible. You might enjoy the book, although I'll throw out the caveat that I am not sufficiently experienced to really judge its quality.